# Core Data with NSFetchedResultsController: Updating Data After Changes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've been playing with Core Data for the past 18 hours or so.  I'm fetching data with `NSFetchedResultsController` and shows data with `UITableView`.  Adding a new record and deleting the selected record aren't my problems.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    // MARK: - Instance variables
    private let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Profiles") // core data model file (.xcdatamodeld)
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?

    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // loading persistentContainer //
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (persistentStoreDescription, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to Load Persistent Store")
            } else {
                do {
                    try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
                } catch {
                    let fetchError = error as NSError
                    print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }

        // notifications //
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(profileDidUpdate), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "HomeViewControllerPictureDidSelect"), object: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - fetchedResultsController(controller with the entity)
    fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Person> = {
        // Create Fetch Request with Entity
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()

        // Configure Fetch Request
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastName", ascending: true)]

        // Create Fetched Results Controller
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        // Configure Fetched Results Controller
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        return fetchedResultsController
    }()
    // MARK: - fetchedResultsController


    // MARK: - Notifications
    @objc func profileDidUpdate(notification: NSNotification) {
        let profile = notification.object as! Profile
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: context)
        let newPerson = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        newPerson.setValue(profile.uuid, forKey: "uuid") // uuid is used to make each record unique
        newPerson.setValue(profile.firstName, forKey: "firstName")
        newPerson.setValue(profile.lastName, forKey: "lastName")
        newPerson.setValue(profile.age, forKey: "age")
        newPerson.setValue(profile.pictData, forKey: "pictData")
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saved...")
        } catch {
            print("failed saving")
        }
    }
    // MARK: - Notifications
}

extension HomeViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch (type) {
        case .insert:
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break;
        case .delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            break;
        default:
            print("...")
        }
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    }
}
```

Shown above, I create a new record from another view controller, which sends an object of a model (Profile) to the current view controller (HomeViewController).  I don't have to reload the table thanks to `NSFetchedResultsController`.

The entity has several attributes (age, firstName, lastName, pictData, uuid).  And I want to change the selected record in the list with two attributes: firstName and lastName.  The uuid attribute is used to identify a specific record.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBAction func editTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
            return
        }
        let selectedRow = indexPath.row
        if selectedRow >= 0 {
            editRecord(index: selectedRow)
        }
    }

    func editRecord(index: Int) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        let person = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        let uuid = person.uuid!
        let context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuid == %@", uuid)
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            if (result.count > 0) {
                let managedObject = result[0] as! NSManagedObject
                managedObject.setValue("Donald", forKey: "firstName")
                managedObject.setValue("Washington", forKey: "lastName")
                try context.save()
                print("Changes saved...")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I click on the edit button, the app won't update the list immediately.  If I restart the app, I see changes.  So how can I update the table with `NSFetchedResultsController` when I make changes to the selected record?  Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `profileDidUpdate` notification? You're adding an observer for that, but where is that notification being sent from?

Comment: @Sam Fischer I've said it's used to add a new record from another view controller.

Comment: Since you're using `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`, shouldn't you be handling the `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.update` case in your `didChange` method ? Right now, you're only handling the `.insert`. and `.delete` cases.

Comment: @Sam Fischer It looks like it.  I'll look into it.  Thanks.

Comment: Right now, it looks like it's falling back to the `default` case and printing `...`. So, just try and update the entry, and see if `...` is being printed.

Comment: @Sam Fischer I've added case .update to controller's didChange delegate method.  If you post a solution in this regard, I'll accept it as an answer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`, you need to handle (for your particular use case), the following cases for the `NSFetchedResultsChangeType` in your `didChange` method:

- insert
- delete
- update

---

Your function should look something like this:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
  switch (type) {
  case .insert:
      if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
          tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
      }
      break;
  case .delete:
      if let indexPath = indexPath {
          tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
      }
      break;
  case .update:
      tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
      break;
  default:
      print("...")
  }
}
```

Comment: Sam, the app will occasionally go to default even after I make changes.  Do you know why?  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, the way that happens is if the `NSFetchedResultsChangeType` is `.move`. I don't know why that might be happening. Could you describe the behavior a little more? Does it happen when you click update multiple times or...?

Comment: I just enter modified values as shown with func editRecord().  Occasionally, it goes to default.  If I enter tableView.reloadData() under default, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: If you don't have many rows in your `UITableView`, then I don't think that will be a problem. I am curious about why that behavior would come about, but I'm a on Linux machine at the moment, and therefore, unable to whip up a test app myself. If you do end up figuring out why that behavior happens, do update the post.

Comment: No problem.  Thanks, Sam.

Comment: The default case is arising because you are not explicitly handling .move changeType, which will occur if you edit the lastName (which your FRC is configured to sort by) and the new lastName results in the object being sorted to a different position.  The .move changeType can be handled by the tableView moveRowAt method, or by deleting from the old row and inserting at the new row.